# Confusion (possibly due to terminology)

Tags: variance, standard-error, error, mse

Disclaimer.. This is a post regarding help with homework but I have done some work.

[image]

I am stuck between C and D since they both seem right.

First of all, I think since the variance explained by the model is very low compared to variance explained by the residuals, it means there is a large portion of unexplained variability in the observed values (essentially R-squared is low). D may be right but I agree I do not understand the terminology since this is my first statistics course in maybe 10 yeras.

C does not seem to be incorrect either as V is not an estimator of sigma-squared, MSE is. But I cannot link how the C while being correct, would explain the differences in V and S-squared (which is the original question).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:
I went with the below answer. Not 100% convinced so any help would be appreciated.

The correct answer is C.
V is not the estimate of variance of the regression. V is the variance of variable y which is the predicted variable. But S^2 is the variance due to regression.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Rather than editing the correct answer (if you know it) into the body of the question, it's better to post it as an answer to your own question. Either way, please tag this as [tag:self-study].

Comment: Okay thanks! Didn't realize I could comment to my own post. :D